# How can I change the cookie notice image?

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, cookie

With regard to the cookieNotice in Magento CE 1.9.2 ("This website requires cookies to provide all of its features..."), does anyone know how to change the image displayed?

It defaults to the Magento logo, I'd prefer to change it to my store's logo though :)

Thanks for any help you can provide!

[image: cookie notice]

Comment: can you add screenshot here?

Comment: Hi Akhilesh, post updated with screenshot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I am not sure if you are using any custom theme or default RWD Magento theme.**

In RWD theme it is calling from `style.css`. It is set as background image in class `.global-site-notice .notice-inner`.

If it is same in your case also you will need to change in css.

And in default Magento, phtml file for this cookie notice called from

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\cookienotice.phtml
```

If you will need to change anything in this file you will need to copy this file in your theme template folder.

Comment: Hi Akhilesh, I'm using RWD theme so in a copy of my styles.css file I've updated the relevant line to be as so, however the image (a small 8kb image) is displayed as enormous and repeats a couple of times on the page. Any suggestions why this might be?: .global-site-notice .notice-inner { margin:0 auto; padding:12px 0 12px 80px; background:url(../images/media/lms_small_logo_image_src.png) 20px 25px no-repeat; text-align:left; }

Comment: It might be need some CSS trick. I checked in my local server and it is working fine. please post your live server URL if you have.